# Atomic sdiffstore + create keys for result

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency, redis, atomic

How to make this operation atomic?

```
redisClient.flushallAsync()
  .then(() => redisClient.saddAsync('myset', ['a']))
  .then(() => redisClient.saddAsync('myset_new', ['a', 'b', 'c']))
  .then(() => redisClient.sdiffstoreAsync('myset_added', 'myset_new', 'myset'))
  .then(() => redisClient.smembersAsync('myset_added'))
  .then(result => Promise.all(_.map(result, newKey => redisClient.setAsync(newKey, ''))))
  .then(result => redisClient.keysAsync('*'))
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

output:

```
[ 'myset_new', 'myset_added', 'myset', 'c', 'b' ]
```

Comment: Have you looked at [redis scripts](http://redis.io/commands/eval)? They are evaluated atomically, but they do lock the database. So, they should be kept as simple as possible.

Comment: @Ben, yes, I know I can do that with a script, but I expected there is a way to do it with more native means.